# Jquery ajax and my php ajax sheet?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using alot of jquery ajax requests for my website, and my php sheet with which the ajax in jquery points to is getting rather long!

I would like to know how many if, elseif, else statements are considered too many?

If I have hundreds will it slow down my site or ajax requests? How many is considered too many, and if they are too many how do I deal with it?

Thanks

Comment: If you ajax is not output by php, but plain javascript, you can minify it. Other than that, your question is hardly answerable. There's not a rule on "how many is too many".

Comment: hundreds of `if else` may be its time for `design` (re)-consideration

Comment: @3nigma not really, in my ajax sheet I have to know what the name of the request is to perform the neccessary database changes, without using if elseif, then I wouldn't be able to determine which query to do

Comment: Well maybe you could split up your requests if they are not part of the same "task". Otherwise you answered your own question...

Comment: @nvcode: depending on how you coded your request codes you could have an array of "request code"=>"php file to request" that will remove the need of all of the `if`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My dear there is no limit of too many. As for as your concern about slow performance it always depends upon your quality of code. If you are writing quality code then there is no problem.

For Example you have sent an ajax request to a file which will return you the records from the table. Now the performance will depend how you write query, how you send back the result, how you display your result. So concentrate on writing quality of code.

Comment: Ok thanks, this is all I was after, thanks for the response :)